# How to control the outer margin on Flot graph

Tags: flot

I am having some difficulties figuring out how to control the outer margin on the [Flot](https://github.com/flot/flot/) graph I have implemented. I have tried many options; minBorderMargin, margin, axisMargin, labelMargin. Neither, set individually or all together, didn't change a thing.

Want I want to achieve is complete control over the width of the right margin.

As you will see [in this example](http://jsfiddle.net/JaC5g/1/), there's a margin to the right, even with minBorderMargin set to 0 (zero).

Here's the source code:

```
var $wrapper = $('<div />').addClass('wrapper'),
    $graph = $('.graph'),
    data = {
        color: '#dba400', 
        hoverable: true,
        data: [
            // [1, 215000],
            // [2, 205000],
            // [3, 0],
            // [4, 70000],
            [35, 270000],
            [36, 105000],
            [37, 60000],
            [38, 0],
            [39, 110000]
        ]
    },
    options = {
        xaxis: {
            color: '#f0f0f0',
            min: 34.5,
            max: 39.5,
            tickColor: 'transparent',
            tickFormatter: function(val) {
                return 'RND' + val;
            }
        },
        yaxis: {
            color: '#f0f0f0',
            tickColor: null,
            tickFormatter: function(val) {
                var units = ['', 'K', 'M'],
                    unit = units.shift();

                while (val > 1000 && units.length > 0) {
                    val /= 1000;
                    unit = units.shift();
                }

                return val + unit;
            }
        },
        grid: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            minBorderMargin: 0
        },
        hooks: {
            processOffset: function(plot, offset) {
                console.log(plot, offset);
            }
        },
        series: {
            points: {
                radius: 0,
                lineWidth: 0
            }
        }
    };

$graph.append($wrapper);
$.plot($wrapper, [data], options);​
```

Bonus question: Is there an easy way to left align first tick label and right align last tick label?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a way to alter the plot, you might consider placing the placeholder div within another div that has overflow set to hidden.  Then you can 'chop off' extra margin on any side by controlling the size of the outer div or placement of the inner.

Comment: The grid.margin property is available in the version I am using, however changing this property to 0, doesn't change anything. It seems from the source code, that the default value is 0 in any case.